# How userful is MIPs and is it worth studying further in Second Year of University?

Tags: architecture, mips

I know there is a similar question (MIPS - How important is it) but I am focusing on how useful MIPs is. I am also studying computer science and after completing my first MIPs assignment few days ago, I was wondering exactly how useful MIPs architecture is. Apparently, for our second year of computer science, I have an option to study further MIPs and its architecture. It made me think whether it's really worth doing MIPs or not. How important and useful is MIPs and is it really worth studying further in my second year of university?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How useful is *MIPS* assembly?

Not exceedingly. Chances are low that you will ever program anything directly in MIPS assembly.

---

How useful is *assembly*?

Very. Although you are still unlikely to ever write anything in assembly, knowing assembly is exceedingly useful in learning how programs you write in a higher level language are executed. Having a background in assembly put concrete understanding behind arguments of "efficiency" that are hard to gather in any other way.

If you are intending on being a career programmer, I highly encourage you to continue study of machine architecture. In my own life I have taken three such "machine architecture" courses and I can legitimately say that they are the most useful courses I have taken in my time at University.